# Got Data in json object from url but can't bind it to listview in android application

Tags: android, json, listview

I am creating android application, in which got data from database as per current longitude and latitude. I got data in json object but cant bind it in listview. Please guide me.

> Blockquote

```
**@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shopdetail);
    aq=new AQuery(this);
        GPSTracker  gps = new GPSTracker(Shopdetail.this);
                   if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                     double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                        getdatalatlog(latitude,longitude);  
                     }else{
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                          }
                    }**
```

the  getdatalatlog(latitude,longitude) method is as below.

> Blockquote

```
private void getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude) {

    String link = "http://192.168.0.104/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude='"+latitude+"'&longitude='"+longitude+"'";
    aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(link, JSONObject.class, this,"jsonCallback");
}
public void jsonCallback(String link, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {             
    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);
    try {
        (success==1)
        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
            map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            mCommentList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE,TAG_USERNAME ,TAG_MESSAGE
                    }, new int[] { R.id.shop_name,R.id.address,R.id.distance
                     });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();    
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });
}*
```

Comment: Please first post your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

please do this may it will help you :

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE,TAG_USERNAME ,TAG_MESSAGE
                        }, new String[] { getResources().getString(R.id.shop_name),getResources().getString(R.id.address),getResources().getString(R.id.distance)
                         });
```

Here i changed your integer type array into String because as you did it was shows your only integer value or blank value.But we want to use resource from android then we have to mention it with get Resource() method.

Comment: The constructor SimpleAdapter(Shopdetail, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], String[]) is undefined

Comment: declare Context class object infront of getResources() mehtod like 
 Context ctx ;
In OnCreate() declare like this ctx = this ;
then ctx.getResourcces() ok

Comment: I cant understand it. Can you describe it in detail?